# Web API Response on some action completion of second app

Tags: webapi

Dear Team i am integrating two application with web api. One application is Mobile app and second one is windows application.I wanted to implement one scenario where mobile app send one request to API and on the basis of request window app perform some action and on completion of that action i wanted to send response back to the mobile app.  how can i achieve this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Is your question related to ASP.net ? Then you should tag it like so.

Comment: If tasks take like few minutes you should use socket.io, if the task is taking hours / days you should use firebase and send notification to phone ,  if you just want to see the status of task when app is open socket.io will be just fine. But if you are going for having a notification or trigger a event on android use firebase...